# Is Serilog MSSqlServer sink supposed to work with Azure SQL Server?

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, serilog, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an ASP.Net Core 2.1 web API that is connecting to Azure SQL Server for the backing data store with no problems.

I am currently trying to set up Serilog so that it writes errors to an "ApiLog" table in my Azure SQL Server database. I am using the [MSSqlServer sink for Serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver) and following the setup described in this [blog](https://www.carlrippon.com/asp-net-core-logging-with-serilog-and-sql-server/). I use the following code in my Program.cs to see any Serilog errors;

```
        Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg =>A
        {
            Debug.Print(msg);
            Debugger.Break();
        });
```

... and  am getting this error;

```
Unable to write 1 log events to the database due to following error: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I do not have any problem connecting to the Azure SQL Server (same server and database but different database tables) in my API's DB Context classes so I am not sure what the issue is. I am using the same SQL login account for my DB Context connections as I am using for Serilog.

Here is my writeto section in appsettings.json;

```
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "MSSqlServer",
    "Args": {
      "connectionString": "Server=<server name in Azure>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Logs;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=<SQL account name>;Password=<Sql Account Password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;",
      "tableName": "ApiLog"
    }
  },
```

I even tried setting the User ID and User Password to the SA login as a test and got the same error so I do not think it could be a permissions SQL Server issue.

So, I am wondering... is the Serilog MSSqlServer sink actually supported with Azure SQL Server? So far I have not been able to find anything specific on the internets that says one way or the other.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried it in a local console app using the documentation as a guide and it worked fine.

```
// This doesn't break/I don't get any exceptions.
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg =>
{
    Debug.Print(msg);
    Debugger.Break();
});

var tableName = "Logs";
var connectionString = "Server=SERVER;Database=DATABASE;User Id=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Persist Security Info=False;";

var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString, tableName)
    .CreateLogger();

log.Write(Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Error, "It works");
```

There was no connection errors.

Documentation example: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#code-net-framework

I made the table myself, I didn't try the auto create: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#table-definition

Here's the row in the table:

Id  Message MessageTemplate Level   TimeStamp   Exception   Properties

1   It works    It works    Error   2018-09-28 17:11:04.1189594 +01:00  NULL    <properties />

Comment: That is with a local SQL Server. My app is using Azure SQL Server.

Comment: I connected to Azure SQL, not local SQL. I created a basic database because this doesn't exactly require many DTUs heh. Then deleted it half an hour later when I was done testing different combinations of connection string settings and serilog options.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that Azure SQL Server works with the Serilog MSSqlServer sink. What version of the sink are you using? I am using Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer v5.1.2. The strange thing is that my API is successfully connecting to the same Azure SQL Server in the Contexts (EntityFrameworkCore v2.1.3) that I configure in Startup.cs -->ConfigureServices, just different databases. I also have Hangfire v1.6.20 configured using the same Azure SQL Server and it is working.

Comment: I'm using V5.1.2 from NuGet.

Comment: Andyj - It looks like the error I was getting was related to Azure SQL Server and the available DTU level. I found out that we had a support team that was running load tests while I was trying to set up the logging. Once they stopped their testing, I was able to get the logging to work without the error. We have since increased the DTU level on Azure SQL database. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the outcome, it was very puzzling. It sounds like that's a pretty tricky thing to diagnose, so I'm glad you managed to get to the bottom of it.